# Listening for the addition of certain elements to the DOM by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web application which uses a lot of AJAX to display pages.
In my javascript I have a feature which gets all the elements that have a certain class (`testClass`). It does a bunch of stuff with these classes but that's not necessary for my problem.

At the moment my function runs when the DOM is ready and it works great. However, I need my function to run when AJAX returns a new page to the browser as it could contain elements with `testClass`.

Is there a way I can listen if a certain DOM element is added? I basically need a way to recognise a DOM change, when this change has happen run my function.
Or is there a way I can listen for the addition of elements with class `testClass`?

If it help here is a snippet of my code:

```
execute = function () {
    var found = false;
    $('.testClass').each(function () {
        //bunch of code
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    execute();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [**ajax success**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: And to test if there are elements with .testClass you can simply use `$('.testClass', $(data)).length > 0`

Comment: Is there another way to do rather doing it with Jquery? We currently use yahoo yui library to handle the connection